# NodeJs: multer uploads file before mongoose data validation

Tags: node.js, express, post, file-upload, multer

I wanted to upload user profile pictures to the server using npm package, multer. So I configured multer like shown below:

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    //Setting up destination and filename for uploads
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {  
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {  
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }

});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{
        fieldSize: 1024*1024*6,
    }
});
```

I also have a user model which stores the email, password and picture path:

```
var makerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, "Please enter a valid E-mail!" ]

    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Password is a required field"],
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength:1000
    },
     imagePath:{
        type:String
    }
},{
    timestamps:true
})
```

Below is my route:

```
router.post('/maker',upload.single('makerImage'), async (req, res) => {
    //Check if image is uploaded(gives no error though)
    var imagePath = "";
    if (req.file) {
        imagePath=req.file.path;
    }

    //creating body for object
    var data = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        imagePath
    }

    try {
        var maker = new Maker(data);
        await maker.save();

        res.status(200).send();
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
})
```

Now when I enter wrong email or password, although the user is not created. But the file gets uploaded to the uploads folder, no matter what. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I see that `upload.single(‘makerImage’)` middleware executes before your handler. So, one of solution - split entering credentials and image upload. You will need separate route for image uploading.

So, firstly, you validate login and password and then make it possible to upload image from UI (using separate route).

Another solution: temporarily save image in memory by `multer`, and then if login and password are correct save it to disk

Comment: How do I implement the second method?

Comment: It's easier to save file in temp folder (as you do, but in another folder), then validate creds, if they are incorrect you can just remove file from temp folder, using `fs.unlinkSync(path)`. If they are correct you could move file from temp folder to folder what you need.